# Python: ImportError: No module named cymru.bogon.dns

Tags: python, installation

Hello am launching a python script and I get this error:

ImportError: No module named cymru.bogon.dns

I really do not write in python and I trying to solve the problem by installing some cymru packages. Any ideas?

```
from cymru.bogon.dns import DNSClient as bogon
client = bogon()
```

Comment: You don't have this package installed. What do you expect?

Comment: what package I should install Malik?

Comment: It's clearly called Cymru, but I can only really help you if you point me to the place where you got the script.

Comment: I put the line of code up, sorry for not give more information, I dont know anything about python, but I need this script working on my computer to continue whit my job! Thank u for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is it [here](https://github.com/trolldbois/python-cymru-services/tree/master) but you need to know how to install with setup scripts and it requires a bunch of dependencies.